# Ubuntu Xen guest: reboot inside guest or use console?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, xen

I can't seem to find any information about using the Xen host (`xm reboot`) reboot command compared to using the reboot command within the guest itself (I'm using Ubuntu guests).

Can I assume the Xen command does the same thing as rebooting from inside the guest, only you can see the console output during reboot?

In which case, and if I'm confident the guest is OK, I could just ssh into the guest and reboot from there if I wanted?

Comment: Do you mean `xm reboot` or do you mean running 'reboot' after you _log in_ to the guest via console?

Comment: I think I'm wanting to compare both. By "console" I mean the thing our ISP gives us to manage VMs. So yes probably `xm reboot` as opposed to logging into the guest itself.